# Dx Warning when run my android application

Tags: android, eclipse, jvm, dx

Hi when I launch the application I get this error repeated several times, and each time with a differente package:

```
     Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.ibex.nestedvm.util.Sort$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

I use Eclipse 4.3 on Mac OsX 10.8.

How can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are probably using Action Bar Sherlock imported as a maven project in workspace and then referencing it as a library from your project..

Try to import it as a Android Project instead!

Comment: any details on how to do this?

Comment: Instead of import ABS as a Maven project, import it as an exsisting android project. That's all! Tell me how can I help you..